# Java: verifying and getting info about HTML tags/attributes

Tags: java, html

I'm looking for some sort of ready-made Java library for verifying and getting info about built-in HTML tags and attributes like the following:

```
public class MyHTMLGenerator {

    /**
     * Accepts tag name and attributes and returns a string containing HTML
     * element.
     */
    public String createElement(
            String tagName, Map<String, String> tagAttributes) throws Exception {
        HTMLUtils utils = HTMLUtils.for(HTMLDialects.HTML_5);
        HTMLTagInfo tagInfo = utils.getTagInfo(tagName);
        ...
        // checking that tag name specified is a valid HTML5 tag name
        // checking that tag attributes' names and values are valid for this tag
        // does this tag is paired or not? which one to return:
        // "<p>" or "<p></p>"?
        // etc.
        ...
        return result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/), which lets you parse HTML into a Java DOM and manipulate it.